# Problem displaying error page running Tomcat 7 in Eclipse Helios

Tags: eclipse, tomcat

When I run an instance of my local Tomcat 7 server within Eclipse, I am not able to display my custom error page.  I have included the following in my web.xml deployment descriptor and have verified that the file is in the appropriate location.

```
 <error-page>
    <error-code>404</error-code>
    <location>/WEB-INF/404.jsp</location>
  </error-page>
```

When I attempt to navigate to a resource that doesn't exists, it should display my 404.jsp page.  However, the browser (Chrome, IE, and FireFox) all display the "Oops this link appears to be broken", or "This page cannot be displayed" page instead.

Is there something I need to configure in Eclipse/Tomcat to allow custom error pages?

Comment: Try placing your 404.jsp outside WEB-INF.  Your other JSPs can remain under WEB-INF since I'm assuming they're accessed via servlet (Struts, etc.).

Answer (score 0):

It should be possible to place your custom error page in the WEB-INF directory.  However, I had an issue with this when a servlet was mapped to the `/*` URL pattern.  You could try mapping to `/` instead, i.e.

```
    <servlet-mapping>
      <servlet-name>wsDispatcher</servlet-name>
      <url-pattern>/</url-pattern> 
    </servlet-mapping>
```